# Writing to file with xtable in R

Tags: r, dataframe, file-io, tex, xtable

I am using the [`xtable`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xtable/xtable.pdf) to produce `tex` output of a dataframe in `R.3.3`. Is there a way to write the output to a file? When I use it I am only able to obtain `tex` code in my `R` console.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `print()` command for `xtable` objects takes a `file=` parameter to write to a file

```
library(xtable)
data(tli)
tli.table <- xtable(tli[1:20, ])
print(tli.table, file="table.txt")
```

see `?print.xtable` for all the options.